# Runtime Error Zone Already Loaded

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angularfire2

I'm trying to add Firebase/AngularFire2 to my application, and after installing the packages and doing the imports, when I run ionic serve I'm getting an Runtime error Zone Already loaded:

```
Error: Zone already loaded.
    at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:128670:15
    at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:129282:3
    at FUNCTION (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:128647:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:128650:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:131700:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:80821:66)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:128166:72)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
```

I was following these [instructions](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/ionic/v3.md) to load the libraries.

When I've looked up this error most people were stating that they found a duplicate include of zone.js and removing this resolved their issues. I searched for zone.js and I have it in package.json and package-lock.json files only. I cannot find it in the index.html.

I also tried this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50089899/runtime-error-zone-already-loaded-in-ionic-3) on stackoverflow.

How would i be able to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug, I went down to another version as per github [comment](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/1081) : `npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.4`